# Customizing jQuery selectmenu dropdown button on after item selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm looking to create a dropdown for colors that has each color as a small square next to the item.

Have:

[image]

Want (roughly):

[image]

[This version (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/1fa2oc2c/) works fine for the dropdown items themselves, but I'd like the button to also update to have the colored square next to it.

```
$.widget("custom.coloriconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {  
  _renderItem: function (ul, item) {  
    var li = $("<li>", {text: item.label});  
    var bgColorStyle = 'background-color:' + item.element.attr("data-color");  
    var fullStyle = "float: left; width: 21px; height: 19px; margin-right: 7px;" + bgColorStyle;  
    $("<div>", {style: fullStyle}).appendTo(li);  
    return li.appendTo(ul);  
  }
});  

$("#selectId").coloriconselectmenu({icons: {button: "custom-button"}});
```

Is there a good way to modify the dropdown button on value update to include the color square like in the dropdown?

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code as follows so that it responds to the `change` event:

```
$( "#selectId" ).coloriconselectmenu({ 
    icons: { button: "custom-button" }, 
    change: function(event, ui){ 
        var selectedColor = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-color");
        //alert(selectedColor);
        var hiddenSelectMenuBtn = "#" + $(this).attr("id")+"-button .ui-selectmenu-text"
        //alert($(hiddenSelectMenuBtn).text());

        var fullStyle = "float: left; width: 21px; height: 19px; margin-right: 7px; background-color:" + selectedColor;  
        $("<span>", {style: fullStyle}).prependTo($(hiddenSelectMenuBtn));  
});
```

You need to select the "select menu text", which isn't readily exposed via a function or property.

You can see this in action in the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhend2099/oqwterae/1/).