# jquery coloriconselectmenu with color on init

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to make jquery select menu with color to select
I found this example and its great
[Customizing jQuery selectmenu dropdown button on after item selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528317/customizing-jquery-selectmenu-dropdown-button-on-after-item-selected/46837623#46837623)

But I need it to initialize with that color Square. Now it only adds to main select color squere on change.

Any one knows ansfer for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `selected="selected"` attribute in your HTML. For example, if you want Red selected, it may look like:

```
<select id="selectId">
    <option data-color="blue">Blue</option>
    <option data-color="green">Green</option>
    <option data-color="red" selected="selected">Red</option>
</select>
```

You won't need to make any other code changes.

Comment: omg that was so easy, basic knowlage :) Why didny I notice it? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Did you try input type="color"?

```html
<input type="color"/>
```